# How to escape "{0:F2}" in StringFormat="{0:F2}" as a string instead of binding expression?

Tags: wpf, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

What is the correct syntax for `StringFormat` in the second label?

```xml
<Label Text="{Binding StringFormat='{0:F2}', Source={x:Static sys:Math.PI}}"/>
<Label>
    <Label.Text>
        <Binding StringFormat="{0:F2}" Source="{x:Static sys:Math.PI}"/>
    </Label.Text>
</Label>
```

[image]

Comment: For impatient readers: Based on the accepted answer, the solution is `StringFormat="{}{0:F2}"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a WPF application?
In WPF, Label does not have a Text property. There is a [Content property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.label?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#:%7E:text=Gets%20or%20sets%20the%20content%20of%20a%20ContentControl.), which is of type object. And therefore for this property no conversion to a string is used and, accordingly, the String Format is not applied.

For a TextBlock:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat='{0:F2}', Source={x:Static sys:Math.PI}}"/> 

<TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat={}{0:F2}, Source={x:Static sys:Math.PI}}"/>

<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding StringFormat="{}{0:F2}" Source="{x:Static sys:Math.PI}"/>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>

<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding Source="{x:Static sys:Math.PI}">
            <Binding.StringFormat>
                <sys:String>{0:F2}</sys:String>
            </Binding.StringFormat>
        </Binding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>

<Binding>
    <Binding.StringFormat>
        <sys:String>{0:F2}</sys:String>
    </Binding.StringFormat>
    <Binding.Source>
        <x:Static Member="sys:Math.PI"/>
    </Binding.Source>
</Binding>
```

Comment: @TheRealMasochist , Read my answer again. I added another implementation option to it.

Comment: @TheRealMasochist, прочитайте мой ответ еще раз. Я добавил к нему еще один вариант реализации.

Comment: @TheRealMasochist , I used the syntax for WPF. Perhaps for MAUI it is a little different. But there shouldn't be a fundamental difference. Only some small nuances.

Comment: Sorry. What is the correct attribute syntax for `<Label.BindingContext>local:MyViewModel</Label.BindingContext>`? My attempt `<Label ... BindingContext={local:MyViewModel}/>`  actually works but IDE warns me with `Type local:MyViewModel is used like a markup extension but does not derive from MarkupExtension`.

Comment: To do this, you need to create an instance of type `local:MyViewModel`. There is no default way to make this a markup extension.
You need to create your own custom markup extension type.

Comment: So ignoring the warning is fine, right?

Comment: You can create your own markup extension class.
Unfortunately, I can't tell you how to do this for Xamarin.

Comment: @TheRealMasochist , I have a custom markup extension for creating instances.
I can show you how to implement it. It will most likely work in Xamarin.
If you're interested create a thread and I'll post the code there.

Comment: I have made the question actually but I didn't use `wpf`  tag because I got downvoted twice. Here is the link: [Is it safe to ignore "Type local:MyViewModel is used like a markup extension but does not derive from MarkupExtension"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74346689/is-it-safe-to-ignore-type-localmyviewmodel-is-used-like-a-markup-extension-but)